# dynamically created flowplayer scrollable addItem scrolls out of the container

Tags: javascript, dynamic, flowplayer, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I am creating a horizontal scrollable list which is also editable. The size of the container of this list is dynamic based on the width of the visible area of the browser. When I have a list of items which has filled up the screen, and I add a new Item, the container scrolls way past the newly added element, to a blank screen. If I scroll back using the "prev" button, I do see it. I've attached code which is used to dynamically add the new item.

I tried to use the .move and .seekTo functions to get to the correct location, but my "prev" button gets randomly disabled so I can't scroll back.

Any pointers from anyone?

```
var speed = 200;
var parent = $("#main-container").data("scrollable");

parent.end(speed);    

var clone = $("#thumbnail-clone").clone(true, true);
var input = clone.find(".text-input");

clone.attr("id", newid);

parent.addItem(clone);

input.show();
clone.show();
input.focus();
```